# Integrate SuiteCRM with Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Database

Tags: sql-server, xampp, suitecrm

I am working on a project with SuiteCrm- , and I would like to use Microsoft  SQL Server 2017  instead of MySql.
For while I am using Xampp server on my localhost to store SuiteCrm-. 
1. How do I integrate Xampp server with Microsoft SQL Server? 
2. Is it possible to connect SuiteCrm with SQL Server - and if it is, how can I do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking two different questions here, but the answers are related.

1. You need PHP drivers for SQL Server in order to use xampp with SQL Server. You can get drivers that support up to PHP 7.2 from [Microsoft's Github repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql).
2. Yes, it's possible, using the PHP driver for SQL Server you installed in the first step above. The database options for SuiteCRM are taken from available PHP drivers, so once you have the drivers working, SQL Server should automatically pop up as a database option for SuiteCRM.